# How could i show only one digit after floating point

Tags: php, floating

```
$f = sprintf ("%.1f",$per);
echo "You hit".$f."
```

By this code i can show only one digit after floating point.But when my result is 100%,then it shows 100.0%. I want to show 100%. how could i do this????

Comment: Do you want to remove the floating point only for 100%, or for any numbers which has no decimal points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$per = 100;
$f = sprintf ("%.1f",$per);
$rounded = round($f, 1);
echo $rounded;
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do this is to cast resulting string into float again after formatting, i.e.:

```
$f=100.44;
$g=100;
var_dump((float)sprintf('%.1f', $f));//100.4
var_dump((float)sprintf('%.1f', $g));//100
```

Comment: I'm working with percentage.I want to show 100% when it is only 100.0%.

Comment: $per = $ok*100/7;
$f = sprintf ("%.1f",$per);
echo "You hit <b> ".$ok." </b> correct out of 7 Questions (<b> ".$f."% </b>) Correct";
Plz correct this code.When the percentage will 100.0%, then I want to show only 100%.